# How do I reset a sum() over () in a SQL Server query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, aggregate-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a derived table that looks like this example:

{select * from tb_data}

[image: tb_data.]

I want the results to have and additional summation column, the catch is I need the summation column to reset the working value if the info column value = 'reset'

{select *, (I assume some variation on sum(number) over (partition by id order by date desc)) as summation from tb_data}

and here's what the output should look like:

[image: desired output]

The actual derived table covers thousands of ids which is why it needs to be partitioned by the id and ordered by date desc and each has a different number of reset points.

What SQL query will get me the output I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first do a conditional window sum to define the groups: everytime a reset is found, a new group starts. Then you can simply do a window sum of `numbers` within the groups.

```
select 
    id,
    date,
    info,
    number,
    sum(number) over(partition by id, grp order by date) summation
from (
    select
        t.*,
        sum(case when info = 'reset' then 1 else 0 end) 
            over(partition by id order by date) grp
    from mytable t
) t
```